# python openpyxl worksheet autosizing column_dimensions - fail

Tags: string, cell, openpyxl

Have got quite far down the track:
Several CSV Files - "Data" loads to data sheet  - format header rows , freeze pane, set font to a fixed type (such as consolas) and auto magically set column width - single CSV data set went really well.

Then did two other sheets and they also went well

Then modified a line of code to include an extra value one of the other sheets and now the automagical column width mechanism is failing (like I say worked previously and still does

```
def as_text(value):
    if value is None:
       return ""
    return value

for column_cells in wsoutData.columns:
    length = max(len(as_text(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    wsoutData.column_dimensions[column_cells[0].column_letter].width = length
```

Works on "Data" sheet

Does not work on "Meta Sheet"

```
for column_cells in wsoutMeta.columns:
    length = max(len(as_text(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells) # This line is failing with "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"
    wsoutMeta.column_dimensions[column_cells[0].column_letter].width = length
```

If it was a syntax issue I would correct but as mentioned this worked on the Data sheet - and did previously work on the Meta sheet - but googling around - the suggestion generally is a code write is somehow attempting to replace the function of "str" with "str" - but I cannot see it ?

Any ideas - as I say it was working and  I added a single variable to an existing record in the source CSV that is appended to the Meta worksheet -

Some cells are empty - hence the as_text workaround.  (Again - these were empty previously)

Happy to share data but that gets specific .?

Thanks

irnerd

Comment: Error reported  # This line is failing with "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Answer (score 0):

Data Specific which is too time costly to investigate.  Reworked old version - used another generated CSV and did not suffer the TypeError: str on an excel cell.